# Can't get tab URL

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome-extension

In my Chrome extension I want to get current tab URL address. In my angular2 component I created string variable to save URL. Then I do this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab){
        this.currentUrl = tab.url;
    });
    console.log(this.currentUrl);
}
```

In the console I get the message *undefined*. So the question is how can I assign Chrome extension function result to my TypeScript variable?

Comment: @vanloc I'm creating chrome extension so window.location just returns me "chrome-extension://...."

Comment: Right. It is not correct in your case. I removed that comment.

Answer (score 1):

The [`chrome.tabs.getSelected()`](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-extensions/A5bMuwCfBkQ) method is now deprecated.

The recommended way of getting the URL of the current tab is to use `chrome.tabs.query()`.

An example usage:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
});
```

This requires that you request access to the `chrome.tabs` API in your [extension manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest):

```
"permissions": [ ...
   "tabs"
]
```

**It's important to note that the definition of your "current tab" may differ depending on your extension's needs.**

Setting `lastFocusedWindow: true` in the query is appropriate when you want to access the current tab in the user's focused window (typically the topmost window).

Setting `currentWindow: true` allows you to get the current tab in the window where your extension's code is currently executing. For example, this might be useful if your extension creates a new window / popup (changing focus), but still wants to access tab information from the window where the extension was run.

I chose to use `lastFocusedWindow: true` in this example, because Google calls out cases in which `currentWindow` [may not always be present](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#current-window).

You are free to further refine your tab query using any of the properties defined here: [chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query)

Comment: I have added permission in my manifest file and it still no luck...

Comment: If I add console.log() in chrome.tabs.query function it print out the url, but after the function ends it becomes undefined..

Comment: If url is `undefined` try reloading your extension from chrome://extensions This will reload the extension's config and apply the newly added "tabs" permission.

Comment: @NikasŽalias, because it's asynchronous. That's how it works. Use the variable inside the callback.

Comment: @NikasŽalias you should close chrome dev tools window before.

Comment: @wOxxOm I can't use it inside callback, because then angular2 http call won't work

Comment: You will have to use it inside the callback. That's how asynchronous JavaScript works.